# Debugger breakpoint hitting on the same line in file but of the different build variant while using lambdas

Tags: android-studio, debugging, intellij-idea, kotlin

We have many different builds, flavors and dimensions in our project. But after updating to Android Studio 3.5 we noticed a strange behavior that when we create a breakpoint in some **lambda** of our file that exists in more than one build variant then the debugger is not working properly and is being hit in the file (of the same name and package) of the different build variant. **Interestingly this whole issue only happens when the breakpoint is set to be triggered in the body of the lambda and is working perfectly fine otherwise**

So in summary to reproduce this issue, you have to:

1. Create two flavors and a file with the same name in each of these flavors
2. Create a code that contains lambda at some line `X` in both flavors

Now only one of the two things will happen but not both:

- When you are in flavor A and you create a trigger on line `X` it will break on the same line but in the file of flavor B
- When you are in flavor B and you create a trigger on line `X` it will break on the same line but in the file of flavor A

Here are some of the screenshots of when we tried to reproduce the issue:

ActualFlavor's AuthRepository (Active Build Variant):
[image]

DummyFlavor's AuthRepository:
[image]

**So the question is what are we doing wrong? Or is it really an issue in Android Studio right now?**

*Android Studio version = 3.5 kotlin version = 1.3.50 build:gradle version = 3.5.1*

Comment: Sounds like a bug, I advice you to report it: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs

Comment: @Enselic It's too few information to consider this as bug. @Muhammad please show build configuration during `run`.

Comment: @Enselic Already reported: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143160964

Comment: I had/have a similar issue that when clicking a File with line number in logcat, it goes to the wrong file if it exists in more than one module

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same behavior with IntelliJ IDEA and Kotlin 1.8.0.
I found some dirty workaround: I added some ballast lines of code to the lambda body like `println("smth")`. After that breakpoints worked.

I think this is a Kotlin debugger bug, not AndroidStudio.